# How i can Close User Control which were open in pop up from another User Control's button click Event in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have Main Window into that i have open one user control child1 and have some of textboxes and buttons into that user control.

When the button is clicked at that time I am opening  user control name child2 now in user control child2 have on close button and on clicking on that i want to close current user control.

Comment: Do you want to switch between user controls?

Comment: I don't understand: you cannot close user control. You can close window that holds user control.
Try to paraphraze your question better a give code example.
People here undestand code faster than letters :)

Comment: No I want to close User Control only not Full window

Comment: You can change its property Visibility to "Collapsed".
Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `Popup` class to open your `UserControl`s
you can close the `child1` when `child2` is closed as following:

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
//Opens the child1 UserControl from MainWindow
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 child1 = new UserControl1();
    Popup p = new Popup();
    child1.ParentPopup = p;
    p.Child = child1;
    p.IsOpen = true;
}
```

UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
public Popup ParentPopup { get; set; }
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

//Opens the child2 UserControl from child1 UserControl
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UserControl2 child2 = new UserControl2();
    Popup p = new Popup();
    child2.Unloaded += Child2_Unloaded;
    child2.ParentPopup = p;
    p.Child = child2;
    p.IsOpen = true;
}

//Closes the child1 UserControl when child2 is closed
private void Child2_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ParentPopup.IsOpen = false;
}
```

UserControl2.xaml.cs

```
public Popup ParentPopup { get; set; }

public UserControl2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

//Closes the child2 UserControl
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ParentPopup.IsOpen = false;
}
```